# SQL ODBC - SQL Error

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I'm using sql server 2014 ODBC database and my program is written in visual studio c++. I want to integrate my c++ program with the sql server 2014 database to do some simple insert and retrieve action.

I wrote a simple test to test out the connection between the sql server and my program. However, the output of my program shows there is a sql error. Retcode returns -1.

please advice.

the output of my program is shown below
[image]

my code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

RETCODE retrieveRc;
HENV retrieveHenv;
HDBC retrieveHdbc;
HSTMT retrieveHstmt;

using namespace std;

void RetrieveConnectToDatabase();
void DisplayResults();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    RetrieveConnectToDatabase();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void RetrieveConnectToDatabase()
{

    cout << "Attempting Database Connection for Retrieving " << endl;

    //Set Environment Handle
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &retrieveHenv);

    //Set ODBC Driver Version
    SQLSetEnvAttr(retrieveHenv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

    //Set Connection Handle
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, retrieveHenv, &retrieveHdbc);

    //Connect to Database
    retrieveRc = SQLConnect(retrieveHdbc, L"database", SQL_NTS, L"", SQL_NTS, L"", SQL_NTS);

    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, retrieveHdbc, &retrieveHstmt);

    if ((retrieveRc != SQL_SUCCESS) && (retrieveRc != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)) 
    {
        cout << "Cannot open database -- make sure ODBC is confugured properly." << endl;
        SQLFreeConnect(retrieveHdbc);
        SQLFreeEnv(retrieveHenv);
        cout << "Press ENTER to continue." << endl;
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << "Connected -- ODBC is confugured properly." << endl;
        string queryDatabase;
        stringstream usernameQueryStr;

        usernameQueryStr << "SELECT * FROM [trackmanagementdatabase].[dbo].[user];";
        queryDatabase = usernameQueryStr.str();
        wchar_t* p = new wchar_t[1000];

        for (string::size_type i = 0; i < usernameQueryStr.str().size(); i++) 
        {
            p[i] = queryDatabase[i];
        }

        if (sizeof(queryDatabase) != 0) 
        {
            RETCODE retrieveRetCode;
            SQLSMALLINT sNumResults;

            // Execute the query
            //wzsInput contains sql statement

            retrieveRetCode = SQLExecDirect(retrieveHstmt, p, SQL_NTS);
            cout << "retrieveRetCode: " << retrieveRetCode << endl;

            switch (retrieveRetCode) 
            {
            case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO: 
            {
            }
            case SQL_SUCCESS: 
            {

                // If this is a row-returning query, display
                // results
                SQLNumResultCols(retrieveHstmt, &sNumResults);

                //display result
                DisplayResults();

                if (sNumResults > 0) 
                {
                    DisplayResults();
                }
                else 
                {
                    cout << "SQL Success else" << endl;
                    SQLLEN cRowCount;
                    SQLRowCount(retrieveHstmt, &cRowCount);
                    cout << "cRowCount: " << cRowCount << endl;

                    if (cRowCount >= 0)
                    {
                        wprintf(L"%Id %s affected\n",
                            cRowCount,
                            cRowCount == 1 ? L"row" : L"rows");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case SQL_ERROR: 
            {
                break;
            }

            default:
                fwprintf(stderr, L"Unexpected return code %hd!\n", retrieveRetCode);
                cout << "it came in here default" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

void DisplayResults()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the SQLError state and error description. Odds are good you can work out the problem from there.